# Finding the missing number from a sequence

Tags: algorithms

I came across the following problem in the book I'm reading:

A sequence $S$ contains $n − 1$ unique integers in the range $[0, n − 1]$, 
that is, there is one number from this range that is not in $S$. Design an 
$O(n)$-time algorithm for finding that number. You are only allowed to use 
$O(1)$ additional space besides the sequence $S$ itself.

Here's how I attempted it:

Let the additional $O(1)$ space be used up by a variable $x$. First, we obtain the $\Sigma \; i$ where $i \in S$ using $x$ to store it. Let's call this sum $S_1$. Now we replace the first element of this sequence with this sum, so that our sequence becomes $[S_1, a_1, a_2, . . . ]$. $x$ is now again usable, which we use to get the sum $S_2 = \Sigma_0^{n-1} \; i$. Then, $S_2$ minus the first element of $S$ gives the answer.

All well and fine, except that I've distorted the original sequence. I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution, preserving the original sequence.

Comment: $x=n(n-1)/2-a_1-a_2-\ldots-a_{n-1}$ would work? This may also be done by substituting every $a_k$ in $S$ by $n/2-a_k$ and them summing up all the elements.

Comment: @Aretino Ah, but wouldn't that violate the constraint of only $O(1)$ space extra? Where are we going to store both $x$ and $n(n-1)/2$?

Comment: See my edit at previous comment then.

Comment: $O(1)$ additional space means a constant amount of extra space. So you can store $x = \sum_{i\in S} i$ and $y = n(n-1)/2$ and just return $y - x$.

Comment: @K.Miller Ah, my bad! I didn't know that. Just looked it up and realized that $O(1)$ means 'amount of space independent of input size'. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. That's a pretty fun little question.

Comment: @Aretino Elegant indeed! Do you mind posting this as an answer?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute every $a_k$ in $S$ by $n/2−a_k$ and them sum up all the elements.

Comment: That is really neat! Now I can have a good night's sleep. Funny how it looks all so simple and obvious now. :D